# How to disable auto re-uploading of `NSURLSessionUploadTask`s?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession

Sometimes (guess if some error occurs) the `NSURLSessionUploadTask` object starts uploading over (from zero byte). How to avoid this behaviour? I want it rather get into failed state. I can cancel it while the app is active if I get its `totalBytesSent` less then previous from delegate. But I get no message if it is in background mode.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same problem (auto-restart on upload tasks) while uploading a file and the reply server timing out.

The work-around/"hack" that I used was to define explicitly the timeout for the request and the resource on the session configuration object.

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration;
//... init configuration ...
sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0;
sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30.0;
```

Since this, the request times out correctly and i get my callback to handle it without the auto-restart.

Hope it helps...